# Error: "Cannot treat the scalar component 'PVtoB'as an indexed component"

Tags: numpy, optimization, solver, pyomo

Variable is not treated as an indexed component. `Numpy` overload?

```
model.PVtoB = Param(initialize=df.PVGeneration.tolist(), doc='PV Generation')     
def market_constraintx1(model, t):

    return (model.Charge[t]<= model.PVtoB[t])
model.market_rulex1 = Constraint(model.T, rule=market_constraintx1)
```

Comment: Possible bug: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/31. Any fixes?

Answer (score 1):

I think because the Pyomo Parameter PVtoB in your case is not given a Set as an index.

Try:

```
model.PVtoB = Param(model.T, initialize=df.PVGeneration.tolist(), doc='PV Generation')     
def market_constraintx1(model, t):

    return (model.Charge[t]<= model.PVtoB[t])
model.market_rulex1 = Constraint(model.T, rule=market_constraintx1)
```